# emulator is out of date error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I tried to start AVD from terminal in Android studio and I am getting following error, Please help

```
 C:\Users\rudraneel-admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools>emulator -avd API_25 -gpu off
    init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
    emulator: ERROR: GPU emulation is disabled.
    Only screen size of 800 X 1280 or smaller is supported when GPU emulation is disabled.
    emulator: ERROR: GPU emulation is disabled: software gpu and screen too large
    Hax is enabled
    Hax ram_size 0x60000000
    HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
    audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
    qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
    audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
    emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

    Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
     - Start Android Studio
     - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
     - Click "SDK Tools" tab
     - Check "Android SDK Tools" checkbox
     - Click "OK"
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only screen size of 800 X 1280 or smaller is supported when GPU emulation is disabled.
    emulator: ERROR: GPU emulation is disabled: software gpu and screen too large**

Just create a new emulator. Previous one was created with configuration which not supported with such conditions.