# Android emulator keeps saying out of date

Tags: android, android-emulator

My Android SDK installation (both in Windows with AS and in Linux without AS) keeps on prompting me "Your emulator is out of date".

My Windows AS did not find any update. And my `sdkmanager --list` will list below:

[image]

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Places API: Google Play Services Out of Date on Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597974/android-places-api-google-play-services-out-of-date-on-emulator)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate, one is the outdate of Google Play service and the other is the outdate of the emulator itself.

Comment: over a year with no resolution, this is always a bad sign.

Comment: Judging by this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980028/1101602), you may need to create an new avd. Your current avd may have been created using a previous version of Android Emulator.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Over two years with no resolution. This is really, really a bad sign.

Comment: There is no resolution based on the input provided because the error may not be that the emulator is out of date, but that there is another error not reported by the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

There is no resolution based on the input provided because the error may not be that the emulator is out of date, but that there is another error not reported by the original poster.
Do search on the first error reported by the emulator

```
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
```

OR

```
emulator: ERROR: GPU emulation is disabled
```

OR

```
audio: Failed to create voice…
```

… etc.

In my case, (*failed to open /qemu.conf*) I had to open CMD as admin, open NotePad, and save an empty qemu.conf on the root of C:

```
C:\>notepad qemu.conf
```

as per [Sergio Cabral's answer to Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505749/failed-to-open-qemu-conf-err-2/62025610#62025610)

Comment: To clarify, though C: is most common drive to run from, `\qemu.conf` needs to be touched/created on the same drive emulator.exe is running from (e.g., if the current directory for the emulator.exe process is `X:\something`, then you need to touch/create `X:\qemu.conf` rather than `C:\qemu.conf`.