# "qemu.conf:1: no group defined" crash of emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

What I did: located log, solved earlier "Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2" by creating empty file (as recommended by [Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505749/failed-to-open-qemu-conf-err-2) )

To avoid XY problem - I run into this bug while trying to run arm64-v8a to debug different bug ( https://github.com/tangrams/tangram-es/issues/2199 ) that is blocking debugging of a project that I am actually working on.

Comment: Could it happen that "empty" file is not that empty (i.e. explorer shows that its size more than 0 bytes)? Windows editors love adding #FFFE at the beginning of text file indicating that file is UTF-16. Otherwise it's not clear how this statements could be reached: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/emu-master-dev/util/qemu-config.c#441 (`fgets` must have returned non-null value)

Comment: note to self: I tried bounty here already