# In android Studio, how to fix: "The emulator process Pixel_4_XL_API_30 was killed" error

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, vulkan

I am using Windows 10 x64 with the 20H2 update. I installed Android Studio for the first time recently. I am trying to have the emulator run, but I keep getting the following error in the GUI:

> "The emulator process Pixel_4_XL_API_30 was killed."

Did a lot of research, and tried several fixes but still unable to run the emulator.
I was looking to get more detail on that error so I ran it in the command prompts and got the following result back:

```
C:\Users\fmaz008>C:\Users\fmaz008\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_4_XL_API_30
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:541: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
VCPU shutdown request
deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
```

- For the Vulkan error, I fixed it (...) by switching the graphics from *software* to *automatic*
- For the Quickboot warning I set my AVD to Cold boot
- For the CPU warning I unchecked *Multicore CPU* in my AVD advanced config.
- For the qemu.conf error, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505749/failed-to-open-qemu-conf-err-2), I open a command prompt in admin mode and ran:

  echo # > c:\qemu.conf

This got rid of the errors but the emulator still shuts down right after starting with the GUI giving the same error. The command prompt output is now the following:

```
C:\Users\fmaz008>C:\Users\fmaz008\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_4_XL_API_30 -no-snapshot -cores 1
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
VCPU shutdown request
emulator: WARNING: Not saving state: RAM not mapped as shared
```

Any idea why the emulator keep shutting down and why the GUI says the process is getting killed?

Additional details:

- My CPU is an old Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 760  @ 2.80GHz, and that beast of a computer has 4gb of ram.
- SDK Platforms installed: Android 11.0(R) API Level 30 Revision 3.
- Launching in a tool window is unchecked.
- I have well over 1tb of freespace on my harddrive
- I do not have any weird characters in my user folder on windows
- My AVD is set to Cold Boot, Graphics is Automatic, Multi-core CPU is unchecked.
- SDK Tools:

  - Android SDK Build Tools
  - Android Emulator 30.2.6
  - Android SDK Platform tools 30.0.5
  - Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) 7.5.6

Comment: I have the same problem, mi CPU is an old intel core i7 930, windows 10 21H2, 18GB ram, HAXM v 7.7 installed (Hyper-v disabled) The emulator with API 29 and below works with API 30 and above the emulator chashes and an alert dialog with "The emulator process was killed" appear

Answer (score 0):

Turn out my CPU is too old and incompatible with HAXM. (Despite passing the checktool software)
I ended up using BlueStack and checking the ADB option in the preferences.

Lauching bluestack before android studio works.