# android studio avd the logo animation continues

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQXpB.gif)

please watch my issue for 1 minute
it is not the android logo stucking it is the android logo continuously animating but the home screen doesn't come.

my device cant support VT-x so I use armeabi 7

I installed android studio already but two armeabi devices today they are:-

> - 

```
Name: Pixel_3a_API_21

CPU/ABI: Google APIs ARM (armeabi-v7a)

Path: C:\Users\USER\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_21.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 21)

Skin: pixel_3a

SD Card: 512 MB

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel_3a

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 21

tag.id: google_apis

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.camera.front: webcam0

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 3a API 21

hw.gpu.mode: off

hw.ramSize: 1536

PlayStore.enabled: false

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 1

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 2220

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-21\google_apis\armeabi-v7a\

hw.cpu.model: cortex-a8

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: webcam0

AvdId: Pixel_3a_API_21

hw.lcd.density: 440

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:0e6953ebf01bdc6b33a2f54746629c50

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: no
```

> - 

```
Name: Pixel_4_API_21

CPU/ABI: Google APIs ARM (armeabi-v7a)

Path: C:\Users\USER\.android\avd\Pixel_4_API_21.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 21)

Skin: pixel_4

SD Card: 512M

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel_4

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 21

tag.id: google_apis

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.camera.front: emulated

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 4 API 21

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.ramSize: 1536

PlayStore.enabled: false

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 1

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 2280

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-21\google_apis\armeabi-v7a\

hw.cpu.model: cortex-a8

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: virtualscene

AvdId: Pixel_4_API_21

hw.lcd.density: 440

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:6b5943207fe196d842659d2e43022e20

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

> - 

and [my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQXpB.gif) continues in two device
the avd starts with an error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQNH.png)
then my issue

so I thought to get more detail so
went to `E:\ANDROIDSDKLOCATION\emulator`
and started emulator with cmd

the emulator started again with
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQNH.png)
then my issue
but I got many errors in the cmd

> - 

```
E:\ANDROIDSDK\emulator>emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_21
emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.4.0 (build_id 7453540) (CL:N/A)
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
emulator: WARNING: Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
Failed to open unused/windows_msvc-x86_64/qemu.conf, err: 2
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT +UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:315: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
emulator: INFO: EmulatorAdvertisement.cpp:93: Advertising in: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_3520.ini
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

> - 

these 3 are errors I think causing my issue how to solve these 3

```
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

Failed to open unused/windows_msvc-x86_64/qemu.conf, err: 2
```

> - 

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231709/14862885 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62025610/14862885

I added the vulkan library,
and
in cmd `E:\ANDROIDSDK\emulator>echo # > \qemu.conf`

all the three error I said before is not now

now when I start my avd

> - 

```
E:\ANDROIDSDK\emulator>emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_21
emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.5.0 (build_id 7491168) (CL:N/A)
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
emulator: WARNING: Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software render
ing.
added library vulkan-1.dll
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT +
UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:315: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, sec
urity: Local
emulator: INFO: EmulatorAdvertisement.cpp:93: Advertising in: C:\Users\USER\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_4128.ini
```

> - 

but still my issue...

finally, the warnings I see in cmd

> - 

```
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off

emulator: WARNING: Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.

Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
```

and a [dialog warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQNH.png)

> - 

what can I do to avoid [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQXpB.gif)
I want home screen help!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by going to Google, searching for vulkan-1.dll, downloading it and placing it on C:/Windows/System32

Comment: well i have added library vulkan-1.dll but still my issue

Comment: well now see my post I have edited thanks for vulkan library info but help me